# Troposphere DynamoDB TimeToLiveSpecification

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I am trying to create a JSON Cloudformation template for a new DynamoDB table. I am trying to set the TimeToLiveSpecification but I get errors and the Troposphere documentation isn't clear.

I have

```
dynamoDB = t.add_resource(Table(
    "myDynamoTable",
    TableName=Join("-", [Ref(env), "dynamo-table"]),
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName=Ref(hashkeyname),
            AttributeType=Ref(hashkeytype)
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="sqsMessageId",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="system",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),`enter code here`
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName=Ref(sortkeyname),
            AttributeType=Ref(sortkeytype)
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="text",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="ttl",
            AttributeType="N"
        )
    ],
    KeySchema=[
        KeySchema(
            AttributeName=Ref(hashkeyname),
            KeyType="HASH"
        ),
        KeySchema(
            AttributeName=Ref(sortkeyname),
            KeyType="RANGE"
        )
    ],
    TimeToLiveSpecification="WHAT GOES HERE???"
))
```

I have tried even putting this in as ready formatted JSON, it won't work.
I have tried:

```
TimeToLiveSpecification=AWSProperty(AttributeName="ttl", Enabled=True)

TimeToLiveSpecification=AttributeDefinition(AttributeName="ttl", Enabled=True)
```

`TimeToLiveSpecification=TimeToLiveSchema(AttributeName="ttl", Enabled=True)` (grasping at straws with this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've gone for

```
ttlspec = t.add_resource(TimeToLiveSpecification(
    "ttlspec",
    AttributeName="ttl",
    Enabled=True
))
```

then

```
dynamoDB = t.add_resource(Table(
    "myDynamoTable",
    TableName=Join("-", [Ref(env), "dynamo-table"]),
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName=Ref(hashkeyname),
            AttributeType=Ref(hashkeytype)
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="sqsMessageId",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="system",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),`enter code here`
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName=Ref(sortkeyname),
            AttributeType=Ref(sortkeytype)
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="text",
            AttributeType="S"
        ),
        AttributeDefinition(
            AttributeName="ttl",
            AttributeType="N"
        )
    ],
    KeySchema=[
        KeySchema(
            AttributeName=Ref(hashkeyname),
            KeyType="HASH"
        ),
        KeySchema(
            AttributeName=Ref(sortkeyname),
            KeyType="RANGE"
        )
    ],
    TimeToLiveSpecification=Ref(ttlspec)
))
```

TimeToLiveSpecification is a Class and needs to be imported at the top. [Docs here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/troposphere/downloads/pdf/stable/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this (untested) with the TimeToLiveSpecification shown [here](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/dynamodb.py#L111):

```
TimeToLiveSpecification=TimeToLiveSpecification(
    AttributeName="fill this in",
    Enabled=True,
),
```

Comment: When I go to deploy this I get "Invalid template resource property 'AttributeName'" *sigh*

Comment: @SarahJessica did you figure out what was the issue? I'm getting the same.

Comment: I think that is having extra attributes defined that aren't used in the key schema or elsewhere in the Troposphere definition.